# Parse console input for calculator

Tags: parsing, input, console

I am VERY new to Java (I have experience with JavaScript/HTML/CSS/SQL/PHP and C#).

So I want to make a calculator, where the user types a command, for example:

> calc> 15 + 9

The program has to process user input and deliver the result, which will be 24 in case of the example above.

I know how to build a `switch` statement or an `if`-cascade to decide which operation to process (whether it has to count/divide/...), and I also know how to show the result.

But the problem I have is to parse the input from the user. I want to **parse the input** into **number1 = 15**, **operation = "+"** and **number2 = 9**. 
How do I solve this?

Extended question: how do I solve this:
Example:

> calc> 15+8+4+6+8

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

Code:

```
public class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = null;
        for(System.out.print("calc>");!(s = System.console().readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("exit");System.out.print("calc>"))
        {
            //parse the string s and do the calculation. Output the calculated value in new line.
            //System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Sample Output:

```
$ javac Calculator.java 
$ java Calculator
calc>12+13
12+13
calc>1+3
1+3
calc>exit
$
```

(Note: The calculation of value is not done)